# Add character to Magento price

Tags: magento

this is for Magento. I would like to add an * to all the prices on the product listing page. I've already done some of them, but would like to know where I can add this specifically to bundle, 'to' and 'from' prices. I have looked under app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml and found the price-from and price-to classes. I don't know where in this block I can add the asterisk to the price. I would like to add some code, but it does not want to display everything correctly when trying to post it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit tricky to output different price formats for different product types. But since you have found the CSS classes, why not do it with some JS?

```
$$('.price-from > .price').each(function(element){ element.insert({after: '*'})});
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. JS seems like the better option.

Comment: Could you please give me an example of how it works? Can't get it right

Comment: the code in the answer is already working, I tried it on a test shop. It uses **prototype** but could be easily rewritten in **jQuery**. You can integrate it into your page by adding it into your template file (e.g. template/catalog/category/view.phtml), or better yet, into a js file the catalog page loads.